# boxplot(), column object not found

Tags: r, boxplot

I read in a csv file and print it:

```
myfile<-read.csv(file="myfile.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
myfile
```

It looks correct, there are 11 columns (V1-V11).

Then I do:

```
myfile$V12<-cut(myfile$V1,breaks=c(0,33,66,100))

boxplot(V11-V12,data=myfile)
    Error in boxplot(V11 - V12, data = myfile) : object 'V11' not found
```

If I read in the file again without `cut` and do something like `boxplot(V1-V2,data=myfile)`, it gives me the same error but with `V1`.  `boxplot(V3-V4,data=myfile)` would throw the error on `V3`, and so on.  I don't think `cut` is the problem.

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: Why would you pass `private`  to `boxplot.formula` when the object as named `myfile`????

Comment: @BondedDust woops, I forgot to change that.  For simplicity I renamed the actual variable name to `myfile`.  The situation should remain the same.

Comment: My eyes/brain did not notice that you had a dash between the two column names. Try instead putting a tilde in there. Since you didn't actually create a formula with that expression, the `boxplot.default` function was called and there is no V11 object in the global environment.